# How to lower apparent resolution of image in composite nodes (with linear interpolation)

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, interpolation

I need to reduce the horizontal resolution of an image in the composite node editor. Scaling down to 10% and then scaling up by 10x **doesn't actually reduce the detail (resolution)**. Normally you would use *Pixelate* node to "set" the pixels, so detail doesn't return when you scale back up, however, as the name suggests it will use nearest-neighbor interpolation. Is there a way to use linear / bilinear / bicubic interpolation?

[image: Scaling it down and back up does nothing]